# Распределение маршрутизации на двух сетевых картах

Tags: подсети, сеть, windows-7

Есть 2 сетевых карты на одном компе. IP первой: 192.168.0.2  Маска: 255.255.255.0 Шлюз: 192.168.0.1

IP второй: 192.168.1.2 Маска: 255.255.255.0 Шдюз: 192.168.1.1.

При том. Как организовать совместную работу двух сетевух так чтоб интернет был ТОЛЬКО НА ПЕРВОЙ. А все остальное ТОЛЬКО НА ВТОРОЙ???????

Comment: Тебе же я уже ответил на этот вопрос! Что значит "все остальное"? (Подсказка, чем отличается интернет от "все остальное"?)

Comment: Просто не могу понять неужели все так просто? Просто если у меня пойдет интернет через АДСЛ модем то я попаду на большие бабки.

Comment: Поставь считалку или ограничитель на карту, что подключена к АДСЛ. А так, если ты не прописываешь ДНС и Шлюз (при отключенном DHCP), как они смогут туда прописаться? Шлюз забирает на себя все пакеты, что не ушли на один из маршрутов. А так как он будет предназначен для первой карты, то вторая на себя ничего не получит кроме того, что ты явно укажешь.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно разграничение интернета (WAN) и локальных ресурсов (LAN), я бы использовал роутер на виртуальной машине. Просто установите на VirtualBox подобную систему (PFsense, Indian Firewall), создайте бридж на нужные карты и настройте правила фаервола. Ярлык виртуального образа можно кинуть в автозапуск с ключом "тихого запуска". Включаете компьютер и через минуту у вас автоматически настроен интернет, фаервол, прокси, анализатор трафика и что угодно, что захотите еще повесить на этот роутер.